# SignalR dotnet 3.1 webapi hosted on IIS 8 (WebSocket enabled) works few minutes only

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, iis-8, asp.net-core-signalr

I am hosting a dotnet 3.1 WebApi with SignalR on IIS 8 with WebSocket Protocol enabled on the server. The hosted API application works just fine for the first few minutes but stops working after a while and doesn't respond to any requests.

*Client-end is in Angular 11, which works as it should be. but when this happens, the client-side takes a long time to finish the API request.*

And have to restart the application then again it works for few minutes.

IIS log shows this error

`System.InvalidOperationException: The 'InvokeCoreAsync' method cannot be called if the connection is not active`

Searched for this error but nothing is working till now.

###### Controller Constructure

```cs
/**
   Controller Constructure
**/
        private IDataTracker _iDataTracker;
        private HubConnection _signalRHubConnection;

        public DataTrackingController(IDataTracker iDataTracker){
            _iDataTracker = iDataTracker;
            if(_signalRHubConnection == null || _signalRHubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                _signalRHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://locally-hosted-url/DataApi/dataHub")
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();
                _signalRHubConnection.StartAsync();
            }
        }
```

###### Controller Action

```cs
/**
  Controller Action
**/

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> TrackDataAsync(DataModel dataObject){
      
      //database call
      var resultData = _iDataTracker.TrackData(dataObject);

      //SignalR Client call
      await _signalRHubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendData", dataObject);

      return Ok(resultData);
}
```

###### SignalR Hub

```cs
/**
  Hub class
**/

public class DataHub: Hub
    {
        public void SendData(DataModel dataObject)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR data: "+ dataObject.IQty);
            Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveData",dataObject);
        }

    }
```

Comment: A Websocket is really HTML over TCP.  Normal HTTP makes a new connection for each request/response.  A Websocket opens a connections and keeps it open so you can send multiple request/response on the same connection.  You connection is closing for some reason.  Not sure why.  You can use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a.  Netsta will give you the status of all connection and sometimes if there is an error the error willbe shown after the connection closes.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you can find out the cause of closure.  Sniffer will show a [FIN] on the TCP when the closure started.

Comment: Some servers will close a connection that is idle after a period of time.  In those cases you may need to implement a Keep-Alive which is an empty message that is sent to keep the connection active.  You also may be closing the connection when an exception occurs.

Comment: @jdweng the application pools Start Mode is in AlwaysRunning Mode, for that issue of being stopped by the system process.

Comment: You cannot have two TCP connections with the same three parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.

Comment: Why do you create/open a hub from a controller? The controller instance isn't long-life so the hub can be quickly disposed. Find any official SignalR sample, and you can see the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [@lex-li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) for mentioning the issue with the controller instance. So now the Hub is instantiated with IHubContext and that apparently solved the issue here.

```cs
/**
   Controller Constructure
**/
        private IDataTracker _iDataTracker;
        private readonly IHubContext<ProductionCountHub> _hubContext;

        public DataTrackingController(IDataTracker iDataTracker,  
                                IHubContext<ProductionCountHub> hubContext){
            _iDataTracker = iDataTracker;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }
```

```
/**
  Controller Action
**/

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> TrackDataAsync(DataModel dataObject){
      
      //database call
      var resultData = _iDataTracker.TrackData(dataObject);

      //SignalR Client call
      await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendData", dataObject);

      return Ok(resultData);
}
```